# Aspnet Core - Failed to show date on form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm making a system for exercising aspnet core.

In the system I have a Transaction register, which is already working correctly, and at that moment I am making an option to edit a transaction that was registered in the system, when I click on edit, a form appears with the old data filled, one being Data , but for some reason I can not show the date.

I have already done some checks, which are:

-When I click edit, the item id is passed by the url. In the TransactionModel model, the logged_user_id and the id of the item are passed correctly.

-Every variable that is added in the item object in the LoadStatus method is added correctly.

But for some reason, when it arrives in View the variables do not take the values, they remain 0 or empty

**View**

```
@model TransacaoModel

    <h3>Registrar Transação</h3>

    @{
        var vData = "";
        var vDescricao = "";
        var vTipo = "";
        var vValor = 0;
        var vId = 0;
        var vContaId = 0;
        var vPlanoContaId = 0;

        try
        {
            vId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Id.ToString());
            vData = DateTime.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Data.ToString());
            vContaId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Conta_Id.ToString());
            vValor = double.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Valor.ToString());
            vPlanoContaId = int.Parse(ViewBag.Registro.Plano_Contas_Id.ToString());
            vDescricao = ViewBag.Registro.Descricao.ToString();
            vTipo = ViewBag.Registro.Tipo.ToString();

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    <form asp-controller="Transacao" asp-action="Registrar">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@vId" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="Data" value="@vData" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Data" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Registrar(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                TransacaoModel objTransacao = new TransacaoModel(HttpContextAccessor);
                ViewBag.Registro = objTransacao.CarregarRegistro(id);
            }
            ViewBag.ListaContas = new ContaModel(HttpContextAccessor).ListaConta();
            ViewBag.ListaPlanoContas = new PlanoContaModel(HttpContextAccessor).ListaPlanoConta();
            return View();
        }
```

**Model**

```
public TransacaoModel CarregarRegistro(int? id)
        {
            TransacaoModel item;

            string id_usuario_logado = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("IdUsuarioLogado");
            string sql = "select t.Id, t.Data, t.Tipo, t.Valor, t.Descricao as historico , t.Conta_Id, c.Nome as conta, " +
                        " t.Plano_Contas_Id, p.Descricao as plano_conta from transacao as t inner join conta c " +
                        " on t.Conta_Id = c.Id inner join Plano_Contas as p " +
                        " on t.Plano_Contas_Id = p.Id " +
                        $" where t.Usuario_Id={id_usuario_logado} and t.Id='{id}'";
            DAL objDAL = new DAL();
            DataTable dt = objDAL.RetDataTable(sql);

            item = new TransacaoModel();
            item.Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
            item.Data = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Data"].ToString()).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            item.Descricao = dt.Rows[0]["historico"].ToString();
            item.Valor = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Valor"].ToString());
            item.Conta_Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Conta_Id"].ToString());
            item.NomeConta = dt.Rows[0]["conta"].ToString();
            item.Plano_Contas_Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Plano_Contas_Id"].ToString());
            item.DescricaoPlanoConta = dt.Rows[0]["plano_conta"].ToString();
            item.Tipo = dt.Rows[0]["TIPO"].ToString();

            return item;
        }
```

If this data is insufficient, just let me know that I share more.

My code is [here](https://github.com/renanosoriorosa/MyFinance)

Comment: Why are you doing your conversions on the View when you have already done them in your Model? Try to access your ViewBag directly instead of converting them again in your View. Something like: `vId = ViewBag.Registro.Id;`

Answer (score 1):

You're using an input type of "date", but you're feeding it a value of `dd/mm/yyyy`. The date input type requires ISO values: `YYYY-MM-DD`. If it can't parse the value it's provided as an ISO date, it defaults to showing nothing at all.

That said, you really need to back to school on all this. You're not utilizing your view model correctly, and you're handling everything as strings, which is not only more error-prone, but basically removes a ton of validation that's baked in automatically. For example, if your bind to a property of type `DateTime`, the user will automatically get an error if a the posted value cannot be converted into a `DateTime`. Whereas, with it typed as string, *any* value will be allowed, whether or not it's a date. If you're thinking you're covered by using a date input type, you're wrong. That could be modified by a malicious user, or even in a best case scenario, not every browser supports that input type, and the default fallback is a standard text input type, which allows any input. I'd encourage you to read the ASP.NET Core documentation *thoroughly*.

Comment: I am studying aspnet core on Udemy, and my teacher is doing this code, sorry but i dont knhow the best practices to aspnet core mvc, i wiil try to do it.

Comment: If this code is coming from a course, then you should request a refund, because that course is jacked. I wouldn't trust anything from it. The ASP.NET Core docs are actually extremely good. If you want something more, Pluralsight has some great courses. It's only $35/mo and you can cancel any time. So, if you can absorb the available courses quickly enough, it'd probably be cheaper than Udemy actually.

Comment: Chris, I put the link of my project in the question, if you can help me, agadeço de corazón. Thank you anyway.